# Finding the velocity when the force is in terms of position

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, velocity

> (The unit of position, mass, time is m, kg, s.)
> On a horizontal line, a force $F=-6x$ (where $x$ is in meters) is applied to a particle of mass $M=3$. When $x=3$, the velocity $v=6$. What is the particle's velocity when $x=4$?

This is my solution.

$$F=Ma(x)=-6x \Leftrightarrow a(x)=-2x$$

$$v(x)=v(0)+\int_0^xa(x)dx=v(0)-x^2$$

$$v(3)=v(0)-9=6 \Leftrightarrow v(0)=15 \Leftrightarrow v(x)=15-x^2$$

$$\therefore v(4)=-1~(m/s)$$

And it appears to be wrong. It's not clear to me what is wrong, but I'm suspecting this line.

$$v(x)=v(0)+\int_0^xa(x)dx$$

It works when x represents time, but in this case it's of position. Regardless, does it really not make sense? We can view $a$ as a rate of change of $v$ with respect to positional change, and I think the equations still make sense.

What did I do wrong, and how can I fix?

Comment: You have a differential equation $x''=-6/M*x $would you know how to solve it? (a(x)*dx  is not a velocity only a*dt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake in your approach has rightly been mentioned in the comments.

A better approach would to solve this would be to use:$\ \ \ {a} = {v}\cfrac{d{v}}{d{x}}$

So:
$$a(x)=-2x \implies {v}\cfrac{d{v}}{d{x}}=-2x$$
$$\int {{v}d{v}}=\int{-2xd{x}}$$
$$\frac{v^2}{2}=-x^2+c$$

$v(3)=6$, find $c$ and you're done!

Comment: What you wrote, $a=v \frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{dx}{dt} \frac{dv}{dx}$, is a beautiful relation I've just understood. I couldn't find it in the book for the class I'm taking (Principles of Physics, Halliday et al.). Is it found in more advanced books?

Comment: Well, this relation is present in most standard books for high schoolers. Never referred to Halliday, so I'm not sure about its contents.